# Why is God's name spelled differently in Sefardi siddurs?

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, shemos-sacred-names, prayer-book

In Ashkenazi siddurs God's name is spelled with two yuds; in Sephardi siddurs we find them spelled as YKVK with the word a-d-o-n-o-y placed inside the last "hey". Also, on occasion, God's name (YKVK) gets three extra vavs.

Is there a reason for this type of printing of God's name in Sefardi siddurs?

I am sure it has something to do with Kabbalah.

[image: Image example of this phenomenon]

Comment: It's a Shtikle too Kabalistic for this site.

Comment: Listen to some of Harav Mansour's Shiurim and you'll get what's going on.

Comment: @HachamGabriel, Eli Mansour? Do you have a link to the appropriate shiur?

Comment: I'll look Beli Neder.

Comment: I believe the extra vavs are only there as vowels.  I've seen the Name spelled out with different vowels under each letter, and the vavs just seemed two special instances of that (shuruk and cholom malei).

Comment: By "with different vowels" I mean "different versions of four of the same vowel".

Comment: The three vav's might come out  with a shiluv havayah with vavin, like in the brachah of sim shalom during the week in the sidurrim that write that out. It would be YvH**vVv**Hv.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about the extra Vavs (do you have an example?), but the YKVK/adonoi is fairly straightforward -- it's a reminder to have in mind both the meaning of YKVK, i.e. "G-d was, is, and will be" (i.e. G-d is above time), and the meaning of "Adonoi" -- "G-d is master of all." (And if you can't focus on both, I believe the latter intent is the most important one, given how we pronounce it.) I've seen it in some siddurim called "Kavanot Hashem" -- what to concentrate on when pronouncing G-d's name.

Comment: see my answer below why two yuds in ashkenazi siddurs

Answer (score 3):

There are 10 ways in which Hashem's name is written in sepharadi siddurim, that allude to the 10 sefirot:

- 4 kamatzim - keter
- 4 patachim - chochma
- 4 tzirei'im - binah
- 4 segolim - chesed
- 4 sh'vaim - gevurah
- 4 cholamim chaserim - tiferet
- 4 chiriqim chaserim - netsach
- 4 kubutzim - hod
- 4 shuruqim (which adds 4 vavs to the name) - yesod
- no vowels whatsoever, or when the vowels are those of l'olam - malchut

I've seen other combinations too, but I have no idea what they mean.

Note that when the vowels are those of Elohim, then the name is supposed to be pronounced as Elohim, not as Adonai. (Usually those follow a place where Adonai is spelled alef-daled-nun-yud.)

Comment: is it merely an allusion or is one supposed to have these or other kavanas when saying them?

Comment: @ray: I think so, but that's only required if you know enough to do so. Otherwise you should focus your kavannah on the plain meaning of the words.

Answer (score 1):

It could be to Metaken the Dinim found in the name of Hashem "Adonai" using the name "YKWK".

The idea is from Harav Mansour but the application is my own guess.

Answer (score 1):

dont know about the second part of the question regarding the 3 vavs (it's kabala stuff), but for the first part:

actually they are the same

the two yuds is a short form for the shiluv of the Shem Havaya and the Shem Adnut. maybe this short hand was done in case the siddur winds up disposed not in a geniza.

*Yud* - **Aleph** - *Heh* - **Daled** - *Vuv* - **Nun** - *Heh* - **Yud**

1st and last letter is Yud-Yud

The shiluv havaya and adnut represents the yichud of the sefirot of yesod and malchut in kabala (whatever that means).