# Vowels around G-ds Name

Tags: tefilla, shemos-sacred-names, vowels-nekudot

[image]

What do these vowels around G-ds name mean?

Comment: These are "Kabbalistic" signs, from what I gather. Do you want to know what each term means or why they are there, in general, and what their purpose is?

Comment: Don't we have this question already somewhere?

Comment: @DoubleAA do you mean [this one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30324/why-is-gods-name-spelled-differently-in-sefardi-siddurs)? see sixth comment

Comment: Maybe this is the answer you are looking for: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/31865/11501 cc @Chanoch